# Удаление свойства объекта в javascript с динамической вложенностью

Tags: javascript

Каким образом можно удалить свойство объекта *произвольной глубины* без использования метода `eval()`.

К примеру есть объект и путь к его свойству `prop1.prop2.prop3`. 
Нужно удалить свойство `prop3`.

Comment: `prop1.prop2.prop3 = undefined;` или `delete prop1.prop2.prop3`? Или вы имеете ввиду, что свойство в виде строки?

Comment: именно удалить нужно было, уже ответили

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алгоритм решения задачи должен иметь вид:

1. Парсим путь к свойству.
2. Получаем объект, соответствующий предпоследнему свойству в пути.
3. Удаляем последний элемент.

Код функции удаления может выглядеть так:

```
var removeByPath = function(obj, path) {
    var keys = path.split('.'),
        currentObj = obj;

    for (var i = 0, len = keys.length - 1; i < len; i++) {
        if (!currentObj.hasOwnProperty(keys[i])) {
            throw new Error('Unknown key "' + keys[i] + '"');
        }

        currentObj = currentObj[keys[i]];
    }

    delete currentObj[keys.pop()];
};
```

А вот и [рабочий пример](https://jsfiddle.net/gwgbamgx/) на JSFiddle.

Comment: В общем то я примерно так и делал, только доходил до последнего свойства (в переменной currentObj) и удалял переменную, в итоге не работало. Спасибо за помощь.